# SSH Tunnel Access

Tags: python, ssh, automation, tunneling

Good Day

I work for an ISP and we basically manage all our switches and routers via the CLI from a Jumpbox.

I would like to automate some of my work on these devices by writing Python scripts, etc.

However, this Jumpbox (Linux), is quite old and the Python version is old. I cannot add Ansible, Netmiko, etc. Plus I'm not an Admin for that box so can't upgrade it.

My question is, if I set up my own Linux VM with all the required tools, how would I be able to access these routers and switches from my local Linux VM?

I tried setting up a Local/Remote/Dynamic SSH Tunnel to the Jumpbox, but I always end up on the Jumpbox SSH session itself.

Comment: even old Python can be very useful - you don't need new functions or modules to use `subprocess.run()` to execute some programs and automate it.

Comment: I never try to tunnel it but with your description I think nobody can help you - not enough information - so we can only say: try harder.

Comment: Ok, in that case, how do I install Python 3 and all the required tools in my home directory on this Jumpbox since I'm not Admin. It should just be for my use and shouldn't affect the whole system. I don't want to use the Python 2 that's on the system.

Comment: Would something like JuNest help?

Comment: why  do you want Python 3? And what tools do you want? And what wrong witn Python 2? Usually you can install `python` in own folder without admin privileges - if there is version precompiled for you CPU and system - and later you can install modules in own folderu using `pip --user`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jumpbox as a bastion host. Copy your public keys to both hosts (the jumpbox and the devices) and in your inventory file use the `ansible_ssh_common_args` option to set it up, like this:

```
[switches]
switch-01 ansible_host=192.168.0.1 ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@ip-bastion"'
```

Note: you must be running Ansible version 2.

Best regards.